# Mysql Left join without duplicate value from left table with the last value from it

Tags: mysql, sql

**tbl_marketing**

```
db_maid db_date     db_customer
1       01-04-2017  xxxx
2       05-04-2017  lll
3       08-04-2017  ggg
```

**tbl_phonecall**

```
db_id  db_mid db_due      db_nextdate  db_pnote
1       2     15-04-2017  16-04-2017   cccc
2       2     17-04-2017  18-04-2017   bbb
3       1     04-05-2017  16-05-2017   ghghh
```

**this my query**

select

```
  select
 marketing.*,
 phonecall.db_id,
 max(phonecall.db_due) db_due,
 max(phonecall.db_nextdate) db_nextdate,
 phonecall.db_pnote
 from tbl_marketing marketing
 left outer join tbl_phonecall phonecall
 on
 phonecall.db_mid=marketing.db_maid
 group by marketing.db_maid
```

The result i want is all rows from `tbl_marketing` even if there are Null values exists in the tbl_phonecall **BUT NO DUPLICATE RECORDS** with the last row from `tbl_phoencall` form the db_pnote,db_due associate to row in `tbl_marketing` order by the db_due from `tbl_phonecall`

My query didn't give me the exact result i want

**the output will be like that**

```
# Date        Customer dueDate    NextDate     pNote
2  05-04-2017 lll      17-04-2017  18-04-2017  bbbb
1  01-04-2017 xxxx     04-05-2017 16-05-2017   ccc
3  08-04-2017 ggg                              ghghh
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: max value is your latest date. Just need to add the left join to the mix.

Comment: @Shadow please check my query above i have create an update but i can't get the last note from tbl_phonecall

Comment: @mohamad_mohamad Which row to select if tbl_phonecall have several rows with the same `db_mid` and `db_due`?

Comment: @mohamadmohamad pls check out the duplicate topic link I gave you, it explains what you need to do. You have not attempted to implement what's there.

Comment: @Devart i don't understand what you say but i want to show the last row enter in tbl_phonecall associate to tbl_marketing using db_mid in tbl_phonecall that contain the id of tbl_marketing

Comment: Think about situation when there are two rows with different `db_id`, but! `db_mid` = 2 and `dueDate` = 15-04-2017 in two of them. Which row will you select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
 select  marketing.*,
         phonecall.db_id,
         phonecall.db_due,
         phonecall.db_nextdate,
         phonecall.db_pnote
 from tbl_marketing marketing
 left outer join tbl_phonecall phonecall on phonecall.db_mid=marketing.db_maid
     and phonecall.db_due=(select max(t2.db_due) from tbl_phonecall t2
                            where t2.db_mid=marketing.db_maid)
     and phonecall.db_nextdate=(select max(t3.db_nextdate) from tbl_phonecall t3
                            where t3.db_mid=marketing.db_maid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to obtain all activity for the latest date in the Phone Call?

```
SELECT 
    m.*

    ,p.db_id
    ,p.db_due
    ,p.db_nextdate
    ,p.db_pnote

FROM tbl_marketing m

    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
            db_id
            ,max(Date) LDate
        FROM tbl_phonecall
        GROUP BY db_id
    ) LastDate
    ON LastDate.db_mid = m.db_maid

        LEFT JOIN tbl_phonecall p
        ON m.db_mid = m.db_maid
        AND LastDate.LDate = p.Date
```